# Correct way to detach a computation and forward context with Reactor

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, project-reactor

In a Spring Boot project, I sometimes need to "fire and forget" a time-consuming task from within an already non-blocking context, and to forward the current subscriber Context to it.

I have an implementation that works but I feel it may be overcomplicated or not recommended. Here is what I'm doing:

```java
    static Mono<Object> longTask() {
        return Mono.deferContextual(ctx ->
            Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(500))
                .doOnSuccess(ignored -> System.out.println("print 2nd: " + ctx.get("x")))
        );
    }

    // Improve me
    static Mono<Object> fireAndForgetLongTask() {
        return Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> {
            longTask()
                .contextWrite(ctx)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
                .subscribe();
            System.out.println("print 1st");
            return Mono.empty();
        });
    }

    // Hypothetical caller
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fireAndForgetLongTask()
            .contextWrite(Context.of("x", "42"))
            .then(Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(1000)))
            .block();
    }
```

Is it correct to call `.subscribe()` from inside `Mono.deferContextual()`? Is there a simpler way to write `fireAndForgetLongTask()`?

Reading the documentation, I was under the impression that I could just do this:

```java
    static Mono<Object> fireAndForgetLongTask() {
        return longTask()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
            .doOnSuccess(ignored -> System.out.println("print 1st"));
    }
```

but this doesn't work for me, it runs `longTask` synchronously and prints "print 1st" last.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use `flatMap`, which connects the context of the downstream to each inner publisher already. Use `then()` inside the `flatmap` function to ignore the result.

Comment: This is not what I mean to do because `flatMap` doesn't detach the computation and return immediately.

Comment: then alternatively to `deferContextual` you could start the computation from a `doOnEach`, but `deferContextual` remains the most conventional way